# Lenovo hardware test "local connection test" failed for Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, thinkpad

My Lenovo ThinkPad T430s occasionally has WiFi connectivity problems where it will work for a few minutes, and then connections will fail even though it is still connected to the AP with a strong signal.  Disabling and re-enabling the adapter always fixes the issue, at least for a few minutes.

I have not been able to solve this problem, but something curious (and seemingly unrelated) popped up in the Lenovo Hardware Test results:

> Local connection test:  failed

[image: Lenovo Hardware Test Failure]

**My question:  What exactly is the local connection test?**  I suspect this doesn't have anything to do with my WiFi troubles, and has more to do with all the VM virtual network adapters, VPN adapters, host file entries, and routing that I have on my machine.

Comment: Are you currently connected with your WLAN? Is there any another network connection (usual LAN adapter, USB-WLAN stick etc)?

Comment: On-board wifi and docking station Ethernet.

Comment: I have the same issue with the same hardware and setup (laptop placed on a docking station with both WLAN and LAN connected) and got this error. So, it might be something peculiar in this setup that perplexes the test and drives it to a false result.